# Integral of a rational expression involving quadratics.

Tags: calculus

I want to solve this integral but I have some problems...

> $$\int_2^3 \frac{(x^2-2x+1)}{(x^2+2x+1)}$$

I transformed both in $(x-1)^2$ and $(x+1)^2$ respectively but didn't find any answer. I tried as well to transform the rational expression into $1 -\frac{4x}{(x^2+2x+1)}$, but I wasn't capable of finding any antiderivative.

Thanks for responding!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax to produce mathemtical expressions, or if you don't know how to use MathJax, please use this site https://www.mathcha.io/editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
I=\int ^{3}_{2}\frac{x^{2} -2x+1}{x^{2} +2x+1} dx\\
\text{Decompose $x^{2} -2x+1$ into partial fractions of $( x+1)$}\\
I=\int ^{3}_{2} 1-\frac{4x+4-4}{x^{2} +2x+1}\\
I=\int ^{3}_{2} 1-\frac{4}{x+1} +\frac{4}{x^{2} +2x+1}\\
I=\int ^{3}_{2} 1-\frac{4}{x+1} +\frac{4}{( x+1)^{2}} dx\\
\end{gather*}Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hints

1. Rewrite the numerator as $(x+1)^2 - 4x$.
2. Ask yourself, what is the $\frac{d}{dx} \log[f(x)]$?
3. What is the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{x^2-2x+1}{x^2+2x+1}=1-\frac {4x+4-4}{(x+1)^2}=1-4\frac {x+1}{(x+1)^2}+\frac 4{(x+1)^2}$$